# sedutils vs hpdarm for SED hard disks

Tags: security, hard-disk, ssd, hdparm

According to my reading there are 2 known methods for using Self-Encrypting Drives (SED):

1. `hdparm`

https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Introduction-to-Self-Encrypting-Drives-SED-557/

2. `sedutils`

https://github.com/Drive-Trust-Alliance/sedutil/wiki/Encrypting-your-drive

Yet, after reading information about each method, I still not sure about the following:

1. Is it that these methods are two alternatives for the same thing ?  Can I used both together ? (for example use one to lock and second to unlock)
2. Is it that the main difference between these two methods is that `hdparm` requires BIOS ATA password feature, while `sedutils` does not require it ?
3. Does it mean that sedutils is preferred way to use with SED drives because it doesn't require a BIOS supported ATA password ?

Answer (score 1):

in this context **SED** = self encrypting disk

***sedutil*** is that software package that is *supposed* to make things work in linux *as far as i can tell*.  So i would not use *hdparm* other than for verifying and diagnosing.

> The Drive Trust Alliance software (sedutil) is an Open Source (GPLv3) **effort** to make Self Encrypting Drive technology freely available to everyone. It is a combination of the two known available Open Source code bases today: msed and OpalTool.

After having purchased more than a few *self-encrypting* SSD's from a well-known hard drive maker, emailing them, and emailing LSI/Avago/Broadcom about the sas raid controller being able to make a SED "encrypt", as well as a well known server motherboard maker of which has TPM, I am finding this *self-encryption* is more of an advertisement and marketing ploy, in my opinion worthy of a class action would not surprise me if people just plug these in and think because they are "self-encrypting" that it all just happens; it does not!

- instructions on how to make it work are almost non-existent

> per your pugetsystem link: Something we discovered when we decided to start offering SED encryption on our systems is that full support for SED is actually very poor. There are plenty of hard drive and SSD models that support SED encryption (although finding those models can be difficult), but full support for SED also requires a compatible motherboard.

- after emailing motherboard, raid controller, and hard disk maker one would think I would have some reasonable solution.  No.
- As an **end user** I think one would need "complete support" from the motherboard to be able to interface with the sata/sas controller to enable or cause *self-encryption* to happen.  this encryption is different than "drive locking" at the sata/sas controller level (because the data on or in the disk is not encrypted).
- The best i found was from a seagate product document on their 1200.2 ssd referencing drive encryption, however I've yet to make "self-encryption" work on my ssd(s).  From documentation i've gathered it boils down to 2 scsi commands happening: *SECURITY PROTOCOL OUT* and *SECURITY PROTOCOL IN*.  How does that happen, I do not know yet.
- Most likely solution seems to be the *sedutil* package in linux and somehow using the command line interface *sedutil-cli*.  This would all be from within the linux operating system as root as far as i can tell so far.
- My initial responses regarding SED were all Microsoft Windows based; it certainly seems SED is still in the development stages and not ready for prime time use (not easily, one should not have to cli or hdparm commands at the levels being described in what instructions exist).  However I do not doubt that a SED is capable of actually doing encryption within itself, but by default it does not happen and that is the problem.

Comment: Why are you talking about motherboard and storage controllers?
To enable/disable security you just use a tool which sent some command to your drive, that's it. Yes, you might have a BIOS on your motherboard which can also send this commands to the disk, but that's actually off topic.
To enable security on you disk just call `hdparm --user-master u --security-set-pass MyPW /dev/sdx`, done!

Comment: `--security-set-pass` you are referring to an *ATA password* which *locks* an SSD at the disk controller level.  That has nothing to do with encrypting data on the disk.  It is simply preventing an SSD from *beginning* to talk to the BIOS/EFI of a computer until unlocked with that password.  Tthe data on that disk whether it is *encrypted* or not has nothing to do with this.

Comment: https://www.admin-magazine.com/Archive/2014/19/Using-the-ATA-security-features-of-modern-hard-disks-and-SSDs

Comment: you very much have to talk about motherboard and storage controllers regarding this... *ATA security is integrated into the BIOS*.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I didn't read anything on that page that confirm you claim that the disk is not really encrypted but only blocked by the disk-controller, but it might very well be true, but very surprising if so. But it might even be the case that SED disks actually always encrypt the data, and automatically decrypt with when no password is set. In my view that would be the most plausible setup, but it's just a guess. That's why the WHOLE disk can be encrypted in a few milliseconds when one enables OPAL 2.0/AES 256 encryption. It actually only switch on/off automatic decryption.

Comment: if u figure it out, let me know.  The ATA password is simply part of the ATA spec and many SSD's now can be  *locked*.  I have locked a basic samsung SM841 disk (common enterprise ssd) and that is not a self encrypting disk.  I have seagate self encrypting disks, have emailed seagate and supermicro, if it was as simple as locking the disk per the ata spec they did not say that.  I save data on a self encrypting disk, yank it and access on another computer no problem, so what is the point then.

Answer (score 0):

`hdparm` can setup the password and also unlock the drive using a password, but it is a userspace application. This means that it can only run after you've already booted your system. If you want to encrypt your boot drive, then `hdparm` won't be helpful. Furthermore, I believe that `hdparm` only works with SATA/IDE devices, and it won't work with an NVMe storage device.

`sedutil` installs an UEFI application that runs during the boot process and allows you to enter a passphrase, decrypt the drive, then continue booting from it.